# Healthcheck metrics blade only shows "count" values

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, health-check

We are trying to test Azure's "Healthcheck status" to be used in an auto-scaled app service.

We have an API endpoint which return status code 200 when it's OK and error 500 when it fails.

The problem is that we don't see any indication on the metrics blade. We are forcing the endpoint to return error 500 during a 10 minutes period every 30 minutes and the metrics doesn't show any difference. We only see "count" aggregation values.

Anyone knows what's is the meaning of "avg", "min", "max" in that blade ?

Additionally, is there any place where to validate the endpoint is being called every minute and the status code received? We are assuming it's working but we have a tracelog -using log4net- that only show messages if we call the endpoint manually but there are no records every minute as it should be if the endpoint is being called automatically.

Help is appreciated

Comment: Is this API endpoint a route on the same app? Or an external endpoint?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara
API's endpoint route is in the same app